# Getting Receive memory warning?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, avplayer

I am trying to take a specific video of maximum 30 seconds from Photo Library with ImagePickerController.

After I'm getting the URL, I'm going in second view to play the selected video in an AVPlayer.

I receive "Received memory warning." and ""Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died".

How can I fix this error? Can somebody help me?

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSURL *videoURL= [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        Edition *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EditionVC"];
        vc.videoUrl=videoURL;
        vc.asset=asset;
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

Playing video in second view.

```
 self.avPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:self.videoUrl];
 self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.avPlayerItem];
 [self.avPlayer play];
 self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(playerItemDidPlayToEndTime:)
                                              name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                            object:self.avPlayerItem];
```

Comment: How did you fix this issue?

Comment: I set a lower quality for video. `picker.videoQuality=UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame1280x720;`

Answer (score 1):

You have memory analysis tools in Instruments.app - this will show you much data related to allocations in your app.

Check app by instrument-->memory allocation

it will show all memory using by app and if there will any leak it will show.

Comment: i know that.   Cpu - 20%, Memory-56MB, DIsk-0, Network-0, FPS-30